# Google+ Sign in - $client->authenticate

Tags: laravel, google-plus

I'm trying to get Google Plus sign in working, with Laravel 4 (MVC framework).

I currently have two methods `home` and `connect`:

```
public function home()
{
    $state = md5(rand());
    Session::put('state', $state);
    $data = array (
        'CLIENT_ID' => 'my client id',
        'STATE' => $state,
        'APPLICATION_NAME' => 'API Test'
    );
    return View::make('home')
        ->with($data);
}
```

This creates the main "home" view with the variables.

In here I have the required scripts, with my button:

```
<div id="test"></div>    
<div id="signinButton">
        <span class="g-signin"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            data-clientid="{{ $CLIENT_ID }}"
            data-redirecturi="postmessage"
            data-accesstype="offline"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-callback="signInCallback">
        </span>
    </div>
```

This then loads my signInCallback function:

```
function signInCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['code']) {
            // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
            $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

            var dataString = 'auth= ' +authResult['code'];

            // Send the code to the server
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'connect',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: dataString,
                processData: false,
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(result){
                        $('#test').html(result);
                    }
                },
            });
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
            console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
```

All of this is working.

How my connect method receives the authcode, and I want to exchange this for the token that is needed:

```
public function connect()
{

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('API Test');
    $client->setClientId('my client id');
    $client->setClientSecret('my client secret');
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

    // Get auth code - this works
    $code = Input::get('auth');

    $client->authenticate($code);
    $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

    return "Token: $token";
}
```

This however returns a 500 internal server error - and it occurs when I add `$client->authenticate($code);`.  Could anyone help with this? I'm finding the documentation very confusing.

Comment: Is the 500 error coming from a Google server or from your app? My understanding is that the error is coming from your app--can you check the logs and provide more details about the error?

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error at the same line of code ($client->authenticate($code);). I was able to fix it by making sure I was using the correct values for Client Secret and Client ID in the Google API console.